# Why ReentrantLock with Conditions can be acquired by two threads in ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

It might be a stupid question but I can't understand why a single ReentrantLock can be taken by two different threads in this class (it's a simplified solution of ArrayBlockingQueue I used to play with threads and locks):

```
class SampleThreadSafeQueue {

        private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        private Condition notEmpty;
        private Condition notFull;
        private volatile int count;

        public SampleThreadSafeQueue() {
            notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
            notFull = lock.newCondition();
        }

        public int take() {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": acquired lock in take()");
                while (count == 0) {
                    notEmpty.await();
                }

                return extract();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            } finally {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": released lock for take()");
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        private int extract() {
            int index = count <= 0 ? 0 : count - 1;
            Integer integer = list.get(index);
            list.remove(index);
            count--;
            list.clear();
            notFull.signal();
            return integer;
        }

        public void put(int value) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": acquired lock in put()");
                while (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    notFull.await();
                }
                Thread.sleep(3000); // let's assume it takes 3 secs to add value
                insert(value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": released lock for put()");
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }


        private void insert(int value) {
            list.add(value);
            count = list.size();
            notEmpty.signal();
        }
    }
```

I receive this result in console:

```
pool-1-thread-1: acquired lock in put()
pool-1-thread-1: released lock for put()
pool-1-thread-1: acquired lock in put()    - this guy has taken the lock
pool-1-thread-2: acquired lock in take()   - that guy has taken the lock as well! wtf?
pool-1-thread-2: released lock for take()
Value = 0
pool-1-thread-2: acquired lock in take()
pool-1-thread-1: released lock for put()
pool-1-thread-1: acquired lock in put()
pool-1-thread-2: released lock for take()
Value = 1
pool-1-thread-1: released lock for put()
pool-1-thread-1: acquired lock in put()
pool-1-thread-2: acquired lock in take()
pool-1-thread-2: released lock for take()
Value = 2
...
```

I suspect it's because of Conditions I use in while cycle but logically can't understand why does it happen.
Appreciate for your explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `await()` on a `Condition` that was obtained from some lock, your thread releases the lock and stops until the `Condition` is notified from another thread (by means of `signal()` or `signalAll()`).

So, your Thread 1 acquires the lock, but then calls `await()` and switches into the waiting mode, releasing the lock that lately is acquired by Thread 2. When Thread 2 is done, it notifies Thread 1 (by calling `signal()`) and releases the lock. The lock is immediately reacquired by Thread 1, it awakes and continues doing its work and finally releases the lock.

Then they repeat it in a slightly different order.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Condition documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

What you need to understand is that Conditions(await,signal) are like Synchronize(wait,notify).  Calling `await()` will release the hold on the lock. (you still have to call `lock.unlock()` tho).  The function `put()` waits for `take()` to trigger `notFull.signal()` and `take()` waits for `put()` to trigger `notEmpty.signal()`.  The locks end up synchronizing directly on the `await()` calls and not `lock.lock()` like you are used to.

This is the documented example:

```
class BoundedBuffer {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```